# Clicking Anchor text of hyperlink in outlook email body

Tags: vba, outlook

I found this script which searches for the hyperlink in the Outlook email body and opens it. The problem is the email received has the anchor text rather than the whole hyperlink and I cant get it to click the anchor text. Any advices. Thanks a ton

```
Sub LaunchURL(Itm As Outlook.MailItem)

    Dim bodyString As String

    Dim bodyStringSplitLine

    Dim bodyStringSplitWord

    Dim SplitLine

    Dim SplitWord 

    bodyString = Itm.Body

    bodyStringSplitLine = Split(bodyString, vbCrLf)

    For Each SplitLine In bodyStringSplitLine

        bodyStringSplitWord = Split(SplitLine, " ")

        For Each SplitWord In bodyStringSplitWord

            If Left(SplitWord, 7) = "http://" Then

                Shell ("C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE" & " " & SplitWord)

            End If

        Next

    Next

    Set Itm = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The LaunchURL code is specifically for use where the URL is visible, such as it is in plain text mail.

Where the link is hidden, you could select the text and take it to Word where there is the [Hyperlink.Follow Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841075(v=office.14).aspx)

---

Edit: Found it simpler not to go to Word.

```
Public Sub FollowLinkAddress(itm As Outlook.MailItem)

Dim oDoc As Object
Dim h

Set itm = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem

If itm.GetInspector.EditorType = olEditorWord Then

    Set oDoc = itm.GetInspector.WordEditor

    For Each h In oDoc.Hyperlinks
        h.Follow
    Next

End If

End Sub
```